# Orchard CMS: Updating a driver for a table with payload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am new to Orchard and have gone through the advanced pluralsight course (which I thought was great). I have built the movie module, which can also be downloaded from the Orchard gallery, but I wanted to add a field for the actor's character name in a given movie. I decided this would fit on the MovieActorRecord so it becomes

```
public class MovieActorRecord {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MoviePartRecord MoviePartRecord { get; set; }
    public virtual ActorRecord ActorRecord { get; set; } 
    public virtual string CharacterName { get; set; } }
```

I also added "CharacterName" to the MovieEditViewModel file. I'm unsure how to wire it all together in the MoviePartDriver when I'm building that viewmodel.
Can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a migration step that alters the table to add the new column.

Comment: Yeah, I had the migration set up - modifying the table wasn't the problem. I added CharacterName to my viewModel, but when I call BuildEditorViewModel(MoviePart part) I can't load the CharacterName from part.CharacterName because it isn't included in the MoviePart, but is actually included in the MovieActorRecord.  How do I modify the BuildEditorViewModel so that I can set the CharacterName?